# Escaping Brackets for jQuery Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm working with some legacy code and trying to update it to a newer version of jQuery. One of the errors I've encountered is that brackets now need to be escaped or jQuery throws an error.

I have an attrib_id that contains brackets like this:

```
group[12345][qf_attrib_12345]
```

This value is stored in the name attribute of a select element. In order to prevent jQuery from throwing an error when I try to select this element I have been trying to escape the brackets like so:

```
var escapeAttribId = attrib_id.replace(/\[/g, "\\[");
var escapeAttribId = escapeAttribId.replace(/\]/g, "\\]");
```

If I alert escapeAttribId out to the screen it has the following value:

```
group\[26782\]\[qf_attrib_16078\]
```

Which is what I would expect. However, when I try to select using this new escaped version like so:

```
var att_default = master_selects.filter("[name="+escapeAttribId+"]").attr('value');
```

some of the time I am still getting an error with the following warning:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [name='group\[26782\']\[qf_attrib_16078\]]
```

A single quote gets added inside of my escaped string. I'm sure this is causing the syntax error. Does anyone know what could be moving the placement of this single quote to inside my string?

Comment: Shouldn't the attribute selector have quotes around the attribute value, ie: `.filter('[name="' + escapeAttribId + '"]')`

Comment: In fact, in a [quick test](http://jsfiddle.net/4g3uwj29/) it appears that so long as the value is quoted, you don't need to escape the brackets

Comment: That got it, thanks @James Thorpe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than escaping the square brackets, you can instead quote the value of the attribute:

```
var att_default = master_selects.filter('[name="' + attrib_id+ '"]').attr('value');
```